# Kohana __() Translation in iFrame

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I actually have 2 questions here:

1. I am using a lightbox plugin that when clicked loads up an iFrame of a page, how to I get it to point to a file in the view folder?
2. Second question will that allow the contents of the iFrame to be translated using the `__()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just point it to a view file, you want to create a route to a controller/action that will eventually show that view; just like you would create any other page in Kohana. And in that case, yes, you will be able to use `__()` to translate its contents.

Example; in the routes file:

```
Route::set('default', 'iframe(/<action>)')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'iframe',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Then you can create a controller `iframe.php` and add the action `index` or whatever other (static, I assume) pages you want to use in an iframe. e.g.:

```
class Controller_Iframe extends Controller
{
    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->request->response = View::factory('iframes/index');
    }
}
```

and then create `iframes/index.php` in your views folder, and voila. You can access it with the url `mysite/iframe/`

:)

Comment: Silly me, thank you so much for that answer, I'm still really new to the MVC Architecture and I always forget to think about it this way.